# How do I make a material with transparency have a foggy illusion?

Tags: materials, transparency

I have a material for all glass in my scene, and it is transparent. Can I add "fog" to the material to give the illusion that it is cold out? This scene is in Blender Render.

Comment: Have you tried volumetrics?

Comment: try [this tutorial](http://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/create-a-foggy-window)